# Flutter: Undefined name 'uid'

Tags: flutter

```dart
class Rapidoreach extends StatefulWidget {
  const Rapidoreach({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.uid,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String? uid;

  @override
  _RapidoreachState createState() => _RapidoreachState();
}



class _RapidoreachState extends State<Rapidoreach> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    RapidoReach.instance.init(apiToken: 'api-key', userId: 'userid');
    RapidoReach.instance.setOnRewardListener(onRapidoReachReward);
    RapidoReach.instance.setRewardCenterClosed(onRapidoReachRewardCenterClosed);
    RapidoReach.instance.setRewardCenterOpened(onRapidoReachRewardCenterOpened);
    RapidoReach.instance
        .setSurveyAvaiableListener(onRapidoReachSurveyAvailable);
    super.initState();
  }

void onRapidoReachReward(num quantity) {
     final DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid); //Here is the error (uid)
        docRef.update({"prizecoins": FieldValue.increment(quantity)});

  }

  void onRapidoReachSurveyAvailable(int? survey) {
    debugPrint('ROR: $survey');
  }

  void onRapidoReachRewardCenterClosed() {
    debugPrint('ROR: closed');
  }

  void onRapidoReachRewardCenterOpened() {
    debugPrint('ROR: opened');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Launch RapidoReach"),
              onPressed: () => RapidoReach.instance.show(),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why do I have an issue saying that `uid` is not defined when is already defined in `StatefulWidget`?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the state of a `StatefulWidget`, you can access the instance of the widget through the getter `widget`, so you need to replace `uid` with `widget.uid`:

```dart
  void onRapidoReachReward(num quantity) {
    final DocumentReference docRef = 
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.uid);
    docRef.update({"prizecoins": FieldValue.increment(quantity)});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the properties from the `StatefulWidget` inside the `State` Object by assigning the `widget` keyword at first :

```
widget.uid
```

in your case replace with this :

```
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.uid);
```